# Hgsubversion: no compatible bindings available

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion

I have to check-in my work into a main svn repo, so I had to setup hgsubversion plugin for Mercurial. That is fine, I cloned the plugin from bitbucket, added the [extensions] hgsubversion = /path/to/hgsubversion, but when I want to use this, I get the following error:

```
abort: no compatible bindings available:

Subversion 1.5.0 or later required, but no bindings were found
Subvertpy 0.7.4 or later required, but 0.7.3 found

Please install either Subvertpy or the Subversion Python SWIG bindings!
```

My workstation uses the SVN 1.6.1 and yesterday the system administrators installed the newest subverpty (0.9.0) packets for me.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is likely to be rather specific to your setup.

First, a bit of context: Although Mercurial is written in Python, it doesn't rely exclusively on the regular `PYTHONPATH` logic for finding its libraries. Instead — to work more like a normal utility — the installed script will modify Python's `sys.path` to ensure that the directory containing the Mercurial libraries appears first. As a result, if a Mercurial extension attempts to import a third-party library, it'll find one installed in the same location as Mercurial first.

So, who installed Mercurial and Subvertpy 0.7.3? Perhaps they both came from system packages in `/usr`, and Subvertpy 0.9.0 was custom-built and installed into `/usr/local`? If so, ask your administrator to uninstall Subvertpy 0.7.3.

Alternatively, you can ask your administrator to install the regular (SWIG) bindings for Subversion. They'll be slightly slower and leak memory for long-running conversions, but other than that they should work fine.

Comment: Both of them were installed by administrators. I could not find anywhere Subverpty, but the admin sad, he installed latest package for my Debian system. Maybe I should ask him to setup this entire hgsubversion for me...
Anyway, thanks for the information.